# How to document react compound components using JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, documentation, jsdoc

How to properly document compound components?

I have this child component

```
/**
 * A React component that provides help text to the user.
 * @typedef HelpText
 * @type {typeof HelpText}
 * @param id - The ID of the help text element (required).
 * @param text - The text message to display (optional).
 * @param cssClasses - The CSS classes to apply to the help text element (optional).
 * @param children - The child component(s) to include in the help text element (optional). could be used instead of text prarameter.
 * @returns A memoized div element with the specified ID and CSS classes, containing the text and/or child component(s).
 */
const HelpText: React.FC<IHelpText> = ({
  id,
  text,
  cssClasses = "form-text",
  children,
}) => {
  return (
    <div id={id + "-helpText"} className={cssClasses}>
      {text}
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};


export default HelpText;
```

I can see its documentation properly when I hover it
[image]

I want to make it into a child of a compound component

```
import HelpText, { IHelpText } from "../HelpText";


interface IFormTestProps {
    children: React.ReactNode;
  }


  const FormTest: React.FC<IFormTestProps> & { HelpText: React.FC<IHelpText> } = ({ children }) => {    
    return (
    <>
        {children} 
    </>
    );
};

 FormTest.HelpText = HelpText;

export default FormTest;
```

How can I make so FormTest.HelpText is properly documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself asking the same question. Then I found the answer and I wanted to share it with you, so I created an account :)

You were very close! When using TypeScript, you can document properties on a type. If you add your documentation to where you defined the `HelpText` property on the type of your component, the documentation will show up in the IDE hint.

```
const FormTest: React.FC<IFormTestProps> & { 
  /**
   * This is the documentation for the HelpText subcomponent.
   */
  HelpText: typeof HelpText 
  } = ({ children }) => {    
  return (
    <>
      {children} 
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is [a TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChSB6AKitLirgEFFj41dIA7JT+GACxTwwOAG7AAJkgDOcfkgA2YODCQAPPhBXy4AV2lIoAOjoMAAjACeYJFMxwAEorAAVdTFNwL1pHADeVjYQ9k5KbhoAvp5mYChQKHiScAC0cC46AJIAInDB2r7ySirucIpIIDzwABREAI66wEQSAJQm9F6x8XiqGilpOj3wFdLSKADmvjBaEsDSYAoolnBVEGAwwBCcKAqt0Z0JcGgjAMILIzJ96b7HAMo3h2cGslNwKGDzSy8CBc7FvWUVXjLVbrTbbXbtGJxA5ofjABQSIicS46WHwiSHDibSpVaTNFRaYCcNAKXRSOBE-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-ifk5nCHr5FD+SBYEQbR9EcUYVnwJWCUQVR8CaRWyzjpOnlIAq3nzm+BYxQx-mFcVcUJSWf7lcK8XOJppVwNV7HChFYFAA) where you can see it working. Hope this helps!

Comment: I will give it a try. Thank you.